# Prove that for any graph G, either G or its complement $\bar{G}$ is connected

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for any graph G, either G or its complement $\bar{G}$ is connected.

I understand what it means to be a graphs complement and I can see that the above is the case but I am stuck on how to actually prove it.

Any suggestions would be great.